# scala, parameter type in structural refinement

Tags: scala, akka

When I compile following code with Scala 2.11.1 and Akka 2.3.4, I get Error:

```
Error:(24, 35) Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
  def behavior(list: List[T], ele: T):Receive={
                              ^
Error:(24, 35) Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to a type member of that refinement
  def behavior(list: List[T], ele: T):Receive={
                              ^
```

The code:

```
package exp

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props, Actor}

trait myTrait[T <: myTrait[T]]{
  def computeDistance(that: T): Double
}


class otherClass[T <: myTrait[T]](){

  def func(data: List[T]):List[String]={

    val system = ActorSystem()
    system.actorOf(Props(new Actor{
      case object START
      case class Job(e1: T, e2: T)

      def receive = {
        case START =>
          context become behavior(data.tail, data.head)
      }

      def behavior(list: List[T], ele: T):Receive={
        case _ =>
          sender ! Job(list.head, ele)
          context become behavior(list.tail, ele)
      }
    }))
    List.empty[String]
  }
}

object Test {
  class myClass(val x:Double) extends myTrait[myClass]{
    override def computeDistance(that: myClass): Double = this.x - that.x
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val fc = new otherClass[myClass]()
    fc.func(List.empty[myClass])
  }
}
```

The reason I define myTrait as myTrait[T <: myTrait[T]] is that I want subclass of myTrait can override computeDistance method with subclass argument. Follows this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199254/overriding-subclass-methods-with-subclassed-arguments).

otherClass provides a method func to produce some computation on a list of myClass instances. (Actually the above code is an abstraction of my need.)

Adding generic type on behavior can eliminate the above error, but it will cause new error.

```
def behavior[S](list: List[T], ele: S):Receive={
  case _ =>
    sender ! Job(list.head, ele)
    context become behavior(list.tail, ele)
}
```

Then, in Job(list.head, ele), the ele of type S mismatches type T.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you make a self-contained example? When I compile your code, I get no error. Also, which version of Scala?

Comment: @Owen Hi, I have made it a self-contained example. I use Scala 2.11.1, and akka 2.3.4. When I compile the above code, I get an error as described in the post. I guess earlier version of Scala, may compile successful, but meet runtime error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a type annotation to widen the type to plain `Actor` fixes the problem:

```
system.actorOf(Props(new Actor{
    // ...
}: Actor))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I have another question about this. What's the difference between new Actor{} and new Actor{}:Actor ? Is not new Actor{} of type Actor?

Comment: @WuCiaWe `Actor { def behavior ... }` is a structural refinement type and a subtype of `Actor`. I've never fully understood when scala will and will not infer a refinement type, but for some reason this case it does. Since `Actor { ... }` is a subtype of `Actor`, you can type it up to its supertype with an explicit type annotation.

Answer (score 4):

```
class otherClass[T <: myTrait[T]](){

  def func(data: List[T]):List[String]={

    val system = ActorSystem()
    class FooActor extends Actor {
      case object START
      case class Job(e1: T, e2: T)

      def receive = {
        case START =>
          context become behavior(data.tail, data.head)
      }

      def behavior(list: List[T], ele: T):Receive={
        case _ =>
          sender ! Job(list.head, ele)
          context become behavior(list.tail, ele)
      }
    }
    system.actorOf(Props(new FooActor))
    List.empty[String]
  }
}
```

Just get ride of that `structural` actor creation by wrapping it as a new class

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I think Owen's method is more neat, so I accept his.

Answer (score 1):

Add generic type for behavior method:

```
def behavior[T](map: HashMap[Int, List[T]], list: List[(T, Int)], ele: T):Receive={
    case _ =>
}
```

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1906
you can't use the abstract type defined outside the structural type due to missing type information at runtime.
Check this answer, [Using Scala structural types with abstract types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726364/using-scala-structural-types-with-abstract-types).